# How to calculate the c-index directly from risk scores in R?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am doing a survival analysis. Below are the risk scores I got based on the test set and the model:

```
risk_scores <- c(0.4995992, 0.5475576, 0.4896132, 0.5176351, 0.5111408, 0.5035943, 0.4995992, 0.4995992, 0.4935940, 0.4879983, 0.5176351, 0.4966655, 0.4995992, 0.4995920, 0.4896132, 0.5779451)
```

Then how to calculate the c-index directly from the risk scores in R?

Below are my status and time variables:

```
status <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
time <- c(455, 210, 1022, 310, 361, 218, 166, 170, 567, 613, 707,  61, 301,  81, 371, 520)
```

I tried several packages on my end but their syntax confused me. Look forward to any help. Thanks!

Comment: Do you also have times that correspond to the risk scores? E.g. the example in https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/nftbart/html/Cindex.html shows how the c-index can be calculated using the inbuilt "lung" dataset

Comment: Yes, I do have the corresponding times. I just updated my question. The example of this function does not work. Look forward to further help. Thanks much!

Comment: It seems that the documentation needs to be updated; the example works if you change `print(Cindex(pred$logt.test.mean, times, delta)) to `print(Cindex(pred$f.test.mean., times, delta))`. I'll post an answer with your example data and show that it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one potential solution using `Cindex()` from the [nftbart package](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/nftbart/html/Cindex.html):

```r
# install.packages("nftbart")
library(nftbart)
#> Loading required package: survival
#> Loading required package: nnet

risk_scores <- c(0.4995992, 0.5475576, 0.4896132, 0.5176351, 0.5111408, 0.5035943, 0.4995992, 0.4995992, 0.4935940, 0.4879983, 0.5176351, 0.4966655, 0.4995992, 0.4995920, 0.4896132, 0.5779451)
status <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
time <- c(455, 210, 1022, 310, 361, 218, 166, 170, 567, 613, 707,  61, 301,  81, 371, 520)

Cindex(risk_scores, time, status)
#> [1] 0.4833333
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-27 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Does this method work with your actual data?

Comment: It worked very well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you solved your problem; thanks for including all the required details :)